# Dell G3 3590 - Geforce GTX 1050 - Laptop Display Wont Work

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics

I'm trying to solve this problem for the last two days, so please help me.

I have a Dell G3 3590 - Geforce GTX 1050. I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 and when a try to boot, I get a black screen with a frozen mouse pointer. After some search on google, I've came across the 'nomodeset' parameter on GRUB. Now my HDMI Display works fine but the Laptop main display is not working. Can anyone help me?

If more information is needed, please tell me how to get it.

Sorry for bad english, not a native speaker.

Comment: Yuri, a question does your presentation any information on the fictional plaque? Were you able to play normal audio on your notebook? I found a solution, but it was relevant to this error. I have the same notebook model as the G3 3590 with Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Nomodeset is for testing and should not be used all the time. Since you are using a NVIDIA card I suggest you are installing the NVIDIA drivers from the "Software & Update" app in Ubuntu.

Just search for "Additional drivers" in your "Activities" and it will install the appropriate drivers.

Remove the "nomodeset" parameter from grub afterwards..